# Is there any robotics package for Mathematica?

Tags: packages, code-request

Is there any package for *Mathematica* that deals with robotics and their application?

Answer (score 11):

The book ***A Mathematical Introduction to
Robotic Manipulation*** talks about kinematic and dynamic modeling for manipulators based on Screw theory. It provides a Mathematica Package for Screw Calculus(click [here](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/books/MLS/software.html) to download). I find it quite useful.

This book ***Modern Robotics: Mechanics, Planning, and Control*** also comes with a Mathematica Package, which can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/NxRLab/ModernRobotics).

Answer (score 10):

Yes, please check out
[Controlling Robots with Lego Mindstorms NXT and Mathematica](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/2013/03/controlling-robots-built-with-the-lego-mindstorms-nxt-brick/)

and

[Denis Cousineau Web Page](http://web5.uottawa.ca/www5/dcousineau/home/Others/Math4NXT/index.html)

Comment: Thanks ..
But what I was asking for is robot manipulators and kinematic and kinetic models of such systems ...

Comment: @M7ammad Please expand a bit on your question and explain exactly what you mean then.